# call object details fron json in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a json file looking like this:

```
{
  "courses": [{
    "Name": "Course1",
    "Containing": {
      "C1": {
        "Name": "C1name",
        "When": "9-17:30"
      },
      "C2": {
        "Name": "C2name",
        "When": "9-17:30"
      },
      "C3": {
        "Name": "C3name",
        "When": "9-17:30"
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

I use a the

```
$.ajax({...
```

function for getting data from the json. However, I can't get the details of the "Containing" part, which I want to call in a for loop.

So I want something like `data.courses[0].Containing.(insert part with for-loop-variable).Name`

How can I do that?

Thanks a lot!! :)

Comment: AppleCow are you around?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use this way with a `.` notation. What I mean is:

```
var container = "C1";
data.courses[0].Containing.container;  // This doesn't work.
```

You need to use the `[]` way:

```
var container = "C1";
data.courses[0].Containing[container]; // This works.
```

Answer (score 1):

Once the JSON is parsed (which `$.ajax` is probably doing for you), you're not dealing with JSON anymore, you're dealing with JavaScript objects with nested properties.

The thing you want to loop through is an object, so you can loop through its properties names using `for-in` or `Object.keys` (returns an array of the object's *own, enumerable* properties) which we can then use `forEach` on:

```js
var parsedData = {
  "courses": [{
    "Name": "Course1",
    "Containing": {
      "C1": {
        "Name": "C1name",
        "When": "9-17:30"
      },
      "C2": {
        "Name": "C2name",
        "When": "9-17:30"
      },
      "C3": {
        "Name": "C3name",
        "When": "9-17:30"
      }
    }
  }]
};
var containing = parsedData.courses[0].Containing;
Object.keys(containing).forEach(function(key) {
  snippet.log(containing[key].Name);
});
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow... `snippet.log()`. Wooh! `:P`

Answer (score 0):

On the same way you can use directly each function of jQuery

```js
var parsedData = {
  "courses": [{
    "Name": "Course1",
    "Containing": {
      "C1": {
        "Name": "C1name",
        "When": "9-17:30"
      },
      "C2": {
        "Name": "C2name",
        "When": "9-17:30"
      },
      "C3": {
        "Name": "C3name",
        "When": "9-17:30"
      }
    }
  }]
};


$.each(parsedData.courses[0].Containing, function(key, value) {
  console.log(value.Name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```